# Formatting Decimal Number

Tags: java, decimal, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am formatting a decimal number and I have the following criteria to format it:

- Number should be at most two decimal places (*10.1234=>10.12*)
- If there is only one digit after decimal then it will ends up with an extra 0 (*10.5=>10.50*)
- Thousand separator will be comma (*12345.2345 => 12,345.23*)

I have written following logic:

```
double x = Double.parseDouble(value.toString());
String dec = x % 1 == 0 ?  new java.text.DecimalFormat("###,###.##").format(x) : new java.text.DecimalFormat("###,###.00").format(x);
```

Now it is printing:

```
11111111111110.567=>11,111,111,111,110.57
111111111111110.567=>111,111,111,111,110.56
1111111111111110.567=>1,111,111,111,111,110.60
11111111111111110.567=>11,111,111,111,111,110
111111111111111110.567=>111,111,111,111,111,104
1111111111111111110.567=>1,111,111,111,111,111,170
```

I don't understand why the behavior changes. How should I print `1111111111111111110.567` as `1,111,111,111,111,111,110.57`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't represent 1111111111111111110.567 exactly as a `double` in the first place. (You can't even represent your shortest value *exactly*, but the inaccuracy will increase significantly as you increase the magnitude.)

A `double` only has about 17 significant digits of useful data anyway - you're trying to get 22 digits.

Use `BigDecimal` if you want more precision - but be aware that this will change other things too. What kind of value are you trying to represent, anyway? Natural values (weights, distances etc) are appropriate for `double`; artificial values (particularly currency values) are appropriate for `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this (You have to use `BigDecimal`):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("1111111111111111110.567");
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
        System.out.println(formatter.format(x));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1,111,111,111,111,111,110.57
```

Resource Links: [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

One more thing, you have to enter the BigDecimal number as a `String` or else it will cause problems.

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(1111111111111111110.567) will output the following.

1,111,111,111,111,111,168.00
```