# Java - Format number to print decimal portion only **without decimal**

Tags: java

This question was asked before ([Formatting Decimal Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330624/formatting-decimal-number)) without an answer as to how one can do such WITHOUT showing the decimal. I have been searching hours for an answer to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Example:

```
    System.out.println("It would take " + oneMileMins + " minutes and " + oneMileDfSecs.format(oneMileSecs) + " seconds for the person to run one mile.");
```

Which outputs:
It would take x minutes and .yy seconds for the person to run one mile.

I would like the .yy to just be yy

Comment: You do realise that a second isn't `1/100` of a minute, right?

Comment: Why not just truncate the first character?

Comment: Are you looking for a general purpose answer to the question in the title, or just a solution to display the number of seconds correctly? (in which case, simply calculating the number of seconds to run a mile, % 60, would give the correct answer)

Comment: @DavidWallace Indeed pardon my sloppy example please

Comment: Do you mean '*fractional* portion without the *decimal point*'?

Comment: Yeah, the best way to do this depends on what you want to happen when the number of "seconds" is less than 10.  Do you want it to say "9 seconds" or "09 seconds".  If you want "9 seconds", then  you probably want to multiply by 100 (60?) and cast the number to an `int`.  If you want "09 seconds", then  you probably want some kind of solution involving either `replace` or `substring` on a formatted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your output to `oneMileDfSecs.format(oneMileSecs).replace(".", "")`

EDIT: Rodney said that "`He did not ask for the proper equation he only asked how to remove the decimal.`", so I strike out the following , to respect him.

<s>***ADDITIONAL NOTE***:</s>

<s>just like</s> @Alan <s>said , `oneMileSecs` should be equal to `(int)((oneMile % 1)*60)`, in this case, the way you get rid of the decimal sign is little bit different **:**</s>

1). If you declare :

`double oneMileSecs = (int)((oneMile % 1)*60)`

then change your output to :

`String.valueOf(oneMileSecs).substring(0,String.valueOf(oneMileSecs).indexOf("."))`

2). If you declare  :

`int oneMileSecs = (int)((oneMile % 1)*60)`

then just output `oneMileSecs` directly as it's an `int`, it won't produce decimal sign

Comment: Why are you declaring as a `double`, but it's casted to an `int`? Just store it as an `int` and don't worry about truncating it.

Comment: Explain for me, because I don't get it. So far as I can tell, it will work better -- you don't need to run `substring()`, you just need to use `valueOf()`. It makes the code neater and more readable. What're the downsides?

Comment: `(int)((oneMile % 1)*60)` will always produce `x.0` if `oneMileSecs` declared as double, so `substring(0,String.valueOf(oneMileSecs).indexOf("."))` will only extract x , remove the `.` sign and the rest numbers behind it, learn more here <a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm">.substring</a>

Comment: Uh, no. By definition, it's an int, so it will just produce `x`. You don't need to truncate it manually. Besides, you're already casting it to an `int` -- why store it as a double if it can never be a decimal value? There's no point. Also, that's not how you do links in markdown.

Comment: read my answer correctly ,, I said `IF YOU DECLARE` , which is i emphasized to `IF YOU`.

Comment: Ah, I misread that as "You should declare". But why would you declare it as a `double` in the first place? That seems to be bad advice.

Comment: @Rodney, I deliver your rejected "Edit suggestion", ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the answer you're looking for, as it doesn't answer the question in the title (Fev's answer does that), but I think this should give a correct result for the specific example:

```
private static void calcOneMile(double mph)
{
    double oneMile =  60 / mph;
    int oneMileMins = (int)oneMile;
    double oneMileFraction = oneMile % 1;
    int oneMileSecs = (int)(oneMileFraction * 60);
    System.out.println("It would take " + oneMileMins + " minutes and " + oneMileSecs + " seconds for the person to run one mile.");
}
```

Or simplified to:

```
private static void calcOneMile(double mph)
{
    int secondsToRunMile = (int)(1.0 / (mph / 3600));
    System.out.println("It would take " + (secondsToRunMile / 60) + " minutes and " + (secondsToRunMile % 60) + " seconds for the person to run one mile.");
}
```